# about intersection of smooth convex sets.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider this article :http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362546X06005372

Let $K \subset \{ x_1 = 0 \} \subset R^n$ is  a smooth ,convex and bounded  domain  .

In the section 1.3 . The author says : Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of smooth, bounded and convex domains in $R^n$such that $K$ belongs to the boundary of the domain. Let $\Omega \in \mathcal{C}$; we denote furthermore by $u_\Omega$ the function fulfilling :

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\Delta u = 0,  \ in \  \Omega (\ in \ the \ weak \ sense\ ) \\
\hspace{-1.5cm}u = 1 \ in \  K \ \\
\hspace{-0.7cm}u = 0 \  on  \ \partial \Omega - K  \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The authors define : $\mathcal{B} = \{ \Omega \in \mathcal{C} : lim \ sup_{y \rightarrow x}|\nabla u_{\Omega} (y)| \leq 1, \ \forall x \in \partial \Omega / K \}$

After this the authors state and prove the following theorem :

Theorem 3 : Let $\Omega_1 , \Omega_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ , then $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2 \in  \mathcal{B}. $

My problem is : Intersection of smooth convex sets not is a smooth set ( for example take two balls) ..

Someone can help me to understand why the theorem 3 is true? I am no seeing why the theorem is true. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, the reference [6] has a different definition of $\cal C$, without the smoothness requirement.